# Create a dynamic php navbar

Tags: php

I am trying to create a dynamic php navbar using and I use a simple template engine.
I was able to create the dynamic navigation but I had a problem when I tried to create drop down menu!
the problem is each main item have many sub items but when i run my script , each main item get the same sub items of the others  main Item had ..

it is like this

```
main item 1 have sub item 1
main item 1 have sub item 2
main item 2 have sun item 3
```

when i run my script i got

```
main item 1  | main item 2  | main item 3  | 
sun item 1   | sun item 1   | sun item 1   | 
sun item 2   | sun item 2   | sun item 2   | 
sun item 3   | sun item 3   | sun item 3   |
```

I need it to be like this

```
main item 1  | main item 2  | main item 3 | 
sun item 1   | sun item 2   | sun item 3  |
```

my code!

```
$site_page_request = mysql_query("select * from pages where parent_id_sec='' order by navigation_order ASC");

$page_title = "page_title_lang_2";
$query_string = "query_string_lang_2";


while ($main_object = mysql_fetch_array($site_page_request)) {

    $links[] = array('link-name' = > $main_object[$page_title], 'link-link' = > "$site_link/".$main_object[$query_string].
        "/");

    $site_page_request2 = mysql_query("select * from pages where parent_id_sec='$main_object[id_sec]' order by navigation_order ASC");

    while ($main_object2 = mysql_fetch_array($site_page_request2)) {

        $links2[] = array('link-name2' = > $main_object2[$page_title], 'link-link2' = > "$site_link/".$main_object[$query_string].
            "/".$main_object2[$query_string].
            "/");
    }

}

foreach($links as $links) {

    $row = new Template("style/template/navigation-row.tpl");

    foreach($links as $key = > $value) {
        $row - > set($key, $value);
    }
    $navigationTemplates[] = $row;
}

$navigationContents = Template::merge($navigationTemplates);
$navigationList = new Template("style/template/navigation.tpl");
$navigationList - > set("row", $navigationContents);

$layout - > set("navigation", "$navigationContents");
$layout - > set("navigation", $navigationList - > output());

foreach($links2 as $links2) {

    $row2 = new Template("style/template/navigation-dropdown-row.tpl");

    foreach($links2 as $key = > $value) {
        $row2 - > set($key, $value);
    }
    $navigationTemplates2[] = $row2;
}

$navigationTemplates2 = Template::merge($navigationTemplates2);
$navigationList2 = new Template("style/template/navigation-dropdown.tpl");
$navigationList2 - > set("row2", $navigationTemplates2);
$layout - > set("navigation2", "$navigationTemplates2");
$layout - > set("navigation2", $navigationList2 - > output());
```

any one have an idea about what should I do!

thanks!

Comment: Not positive this is your issue, but I would change the `foreach` iterator so the names are not the same.  So `foreach ($links as $link)... foreach ($link as $key => $value)... and similarly for $links2.

Comment: thanks but it dose not work, i still have the same issue.

Comment: You could add some debug `echo`s to figure out if you are getting the wrong data in the DB queries or manipulating it wrong.  Could you also update your post with your current code?

Comment: Hi, i add `echo` and there is no errors appears, and for the code which one should i post ? I posted the current one that i have

Comment: Your code in the post still looks wrong... Also, when I suggested to echo DB data, you should get some data back (presumably your submenu entries you are trying to build).  Can you try all of this, then update your post with that code (with the debug statements in it and links fixed) and the output results?